# Why isn't this this email sending/arriving?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to VB, but I looked online for some snippets. This is what I found, everything compiles ,and the email address is correct but I get "Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was:(blank)".
Note: I put a dummy email there.

```
    'Check the humanity of the submitter 
    If strhumanity = "Aggies" Then
        ' Send Email
        Using message As New MailMessage()
            message.From = New MailAddress(ourEmail.ToString())
            message.[To].Add(New MailAddress("sephoroth@yahoo.com"))    'Change back to gerald's email
            message.Subject = "Ecampus Isses"
            message.Body = body
            Dim client As New SmtpClient()
            client.Host = "eforms.tamug.edu"   'Change back
            client.Send(message)
            Server.Transfer("ThankYou.aspx", True)
        End Using

    Else
        Response.Write("You do not seem to be human. Try again.")
        'exit
    End If
```

Comment: Does the SMTP server require authentication?  Does it have a whitelist of allowed servers?  Is your server on that list?

Comment: You're `Using` should be on the smtp client not the mail message. You also haven't passed credentials to that host, is it an internal Exchange set to allow anonymous mail? You should also set the Delivery Method property on your smtp client.

Answer (score 1):

Could be:

- Your process is not authenticated to the mail server
- port 25 is not open

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this for your SmtpClient().
Edit: the port need to be specified too.

```
client.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("foo@bar.com", "this_is_a_password")
client.Port = 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Some won't deliver if there is not a `Sender` on the `MailMessage` object. You also need to specify the `Port` and `Credencials` on the `SmtpClient` object.